# Are Sorcerer spells like Aspect of the Platinum Dragon on Sorc/Wiz spell list for a Sublime Chord?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, sorcerer, bard

The sublime chord spellcasting description states that a sublime chord can choose spells from the sorcerer/wizard spell list or the bard spell list.

Does that mean that the spells must be on both the sorcerer and wizard spell lists or can you choose any sorcerer or wizard spell?

Such as the *aspect of the platinum dragon* spell for example:

> #### Aspect of the Platinum Dragon
>
> (*Dragon Magic*)
>
> Transmutation (Polymorph) [Good]
> **Level:** ***Sorcerer 7***, Initiate of Bahamut (Feat) 7,
> **Components:** V, S, Good
> **Casting Time:** 1 swift action
> **Range:** Personal
> **Target:** You
> **Duration:** 1 round/level (D)
> **Good:** Only good-aligned characters can cast this spell.

***Emphasis*** mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m going to say “no, a sublime chord cannot learn or cast *aspect of the platinum dragon*.”

This is not super-explicit, and there are a ton of semantic questions we can ask about what a spell list is and what source is the primary definition of what is or isn’t on one, but it doesn’t seem terribly valuable to get into those.

Ultimately, there are effectively two sources on the subject of *aspect of the platinum dragon* and whether or not it’s on the sor/wiz list, and neither really helps you:

- The full description of *aspect of the platinum dragon* says “Sorcerer 7,” not “Sorcerer/wizard 7,” so that does not indicate this is a sor/wiz spell that a sublime chord could cast.
- The short description of *aspect of the platinum dragon* appears in the “New Sorcerer/Wizard Spells” list on page 62 of *Dragon Magic*, which kind of implies that it **is** on the sor/wiz spell list—but then you have to contend with the fact that this particular entry in that list explicitly says “Sorcerer spell only.” You’re not a sorcerer, so that doesn’t apply to you—even if the spell is considered to be on a list you have access to, it has a specific requirement you can’t meet.

If either of these was in your favor, you could make a case for why that one should win out, but neither does. Therefore, the entire discussion of which should or shouldn’t be primary is moot.